# Can secret holes be found during Championship or Timed Mode?

Tags: ok-golf

Each course in OK Golf includes two secret holes which unlock a hidden bonus level for use in free play. Sinking the ball in a secret hole will end the current hole without a score, and teleports the player to a new level.

Do these secret holes appear during Championship and Timed Mode? Or can they only be found while in Free Play?

[image: example of a secret hole]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Secret holes can only be found while in Free Play mode.**

Despite what the loading screen hints may suggest, secret holes will *not* appear when playing Championship or Timed Mode.

[image: hole 4 in Championship mode: no secret hole]